# Using Doclava with Ant and Android

Tags: android, ant, javadoc

I'm trying to use Doclava with ant for an Android project but I can't find any good instructions on the web.

I've got the following code :

```
<javadoc destdir="${local.svn.dir}/@{projectname}/${doc.dir}/" 
      sourcepath="${local.svn.dir}/@{projectname}"
      docletpath="/home/martyn/build/jars/doclava-1.0.2.jar"
      bootclasspath="${java.home}/lib/rt.jar">
   <doclet name="com.google.doclava.Doclava">
      <param name="-hdf"/> <param name="project.name"/> <param name="Doclava"/>
   </doclet>                           
</javadoc>
```

but this is giving me the error:

```
[javadoc] javadoc: error - In doclet
class com.google.doclava.Doclava, 
method start has thrown an exception
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
[javadoc]
java.lang.NullPointerException  
[javadoc]   at com.google.doclava.Hierarchy.recurse(Hierarchy.java:102)
[javadoc]   at com.google.doclava.Hierarchy.makeHierarchy(Hierarchy.java:61)
[javadoc]   at com.google.doclava.Doclava.writeHierarchy(Doclava.java:1000)
[javadoc]   at com.google.doclava.Doclava.start(Doclava.java:346)
[javadoc]   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[javadoc]   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
[javadoc]   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
[javadoc]   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
[javadoc]   at com.sun.tools.javadoc.DocletInvoker.invoke(DocletInvoker.java:269)
[javadoc]   at com.sun.tools.javadoc.DocletInvoker.start(DocletInvoker.java:143)
[javadoc]   at com.sun.tools.javadoc.Start.parseAndExecute(Start.java:340)
[javadoc]   at com.sun.tools.javadoc.Start.begin(Start.java:128)
[javadoc]   at com.sun.tools.javadoc.Main.execute(Main.java:41)
[javadoc]   at com.sun.tools.javadoc.Main.main(Main.java:31)
```

Does anyone know how i can fix this?

EDIT:
I get this problem with doclava 1.0.2 and 1.0.3

java.home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.24/jre

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar problem. While the [doclava wiki](https://code.google.com/p/doclava/wiki/CommonProblems) emphasizes to check if the JAVA_HOME enviroment variable is correctly set, I've added path in the bootclasspath without the environment variable, e.g.:

bootclasspath="/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.24/jre/lib/rt.jar"

That fixed my issue (and I know that it is not a elegant solution, but a quick fix). You probably might check if your environment variables are working in your build.xml file?